# win32 winsocket

Tags: winapi, windows-ce, winsock2

I've got a problem and I've been trying to solve it for already a week! But I don't get any information in the internet, which lead to the solution.

The problem's following:
I try to write a simple Win32-GUI-Application for WIndows Embedded. I'm using Visual Studio 2008 Professional. At the beginning of the application, a connection to a server should be build. This is my code so far:

```
// Test.cpp : Definiert den Einstiegspunkt für die Anwendung.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Test.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib, Mswsock.lib, and Advapi32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")


#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"
#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Globale Variablen:
HINSTANCE           g_hInst;            // Aktuelle Instanz
HWND                g_hWndMenuBar;      // Menüleistenhandle

// Vorwärtsdeklarationen der in diesem Codemodul enthaltenen Funktionen:
ATOM            MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE, LPTSTR);
BOOL            InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                   int       nCmdShow)
{
    MSG msg;

    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                    *ptr = NULL,
                    hints;
    char *sendbuf = "this is a test";
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int iResult;
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        ;
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo("localhost", DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if ( iResult != 0 ) {
        ;
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
    for(ptr=result; ptr != NULL ;ptr=ptr->ai_next) {

        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, 
            ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            ;
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        // Connect to server.
        iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        ;
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Send an initial buffer
    iResult = send( ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0 );
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        ;
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }


    // shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        ;
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Receive until the peer closes the connection
    do {

        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if ( iResult > 0 )
            ;
        else if ( iResult == 0 )
            ;
        else
            ;

    } while( iResult > 0 );

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    // Anwendungsinitialisierung ausführen:
    if (!InitInstance(hInstance, nCmdShow)) 
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable;
    hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_TEST));

    // Hauptmeldungsschleife:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) 
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg)) 
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

//
//  FUNKTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  ZWECK: Registriert die Fensterklasse.
//
//  KOMMENTARE:
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance, LPTSTR szWindowClass)
{
    WNDCLASS wc;

    wc.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_TEST));
    wc.hCursor       = 0;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = 0;
    wc.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;

    return RegisterClass(&wc);
}

//
//   FUNKTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   ZWECK: Speichert das Instanzenhandle und erstellt das Hauptfenster.
//
//   KOMMENTARE:
//
//        In dieser Funktion wird das Instanzenhandle in einer globalen Variablen gespeichert, und das
//        Hauptprogrammfenster wird erstellt und angezeigt.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWnd;
    TCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];      // Titelleistentext
    TCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];    // Klassenname des Hauptfensters

    g_hInst = hInstance; // Instanzenhandle in der globalen Variablen speichern

    // SHInitExtraControls sollte einmal während der Initialisierung der Anwendung aufgerufen werden, um alle
    // gerätespezifischen Steuerelemente wie CAPEDIT und SIPPREF zu initialisieren.
    SHInitExtraControls();

    LoadString(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING); 
    LoadString(hInstance, IDC_TEST, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);

    //Bei bereits gestarteter Ausführung Fokus auf das Fenster verschieben und beenden
    hWnd = FindWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle);  
    if (hWnd) 
    {
        // Fokus auf das erste untergeordnete Fenster festlegen
        // "| 0x00000001" wird verwendet, um alle eigenen Fenster in den Vordergrund zu stellen und
        // zu aktivieren.
        SetForegroundWindow((HWND)((ULONG) hWnd | 0x00000001));
        return 0;
    } 

    if (!MyRegisterClass(hInstance, szWindowClass))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_VISIBLE,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Wenn das Hauptfenster mithilfe von CW_USEDEFAULT erstellt wird, wird die Höhe der Menüleiste (falls
    // erstellt) nicht berücksichtigt. Daher wird die Größe des Fensters nach dem Erstellen angepasst,
    // sofern eine Menüleiste vorhanden ist.
    if (g_hWndMenuBar)
    {
        RECT rc;
        RECT rcMenuBar;

        GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rc);
        GetWindowRect(g_hWndMenuBar, &rcMenuBar);
        rc.bottom -= (rcMenuBar.bottom - rcMenuBar.top);

        MoveWindow(hWnd, rc.left, rc.top, rc.right-rc.left, rc.bottom-rc.top, FALSE);
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);


    return TRUE;
}

//
//  FUNKTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  ZWECK:  Verarbeitet Meldungen vom Hauptfenster.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - Verarbeiten des Anwendungsmenüs
//  WM_PAINT    - Zeichnen des Hauptfensters
//  WM_DESTROY  - Beenden-Meldung anzeigen und zurückgeben
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    static SHACTIVATEINFO s_sai;

    switch (message) 
    {
        case WM_COMMAND:
            wmId    = LOWORD(wParam); 
            wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam); 
            // Menüauswahl bearbeiten:
            switch (wmId)
            {
                case IDM_HELP_ABOUT:
                    DialogBox(g_hInst, (LPCTSTR)IDD_ABOUTBOX, hWnd, About);
                    break;
                case IDM_OK:
                    SendMessage (hWnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);             
                    break;
                default:
                    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
            break;
        case WM_CREATE:
            SHMENUBARINFO mbi;

            memset(&mbi, 0, sizeof(SHMENUBARINFO));
            mbi.cbSize     = sizeof(SHMENUBARINFO);
            mbi.hwndParent = hWnd;
            mbi.nToolBarId = IDR_MENU;
            mbi.hInstRes   = g_hInst;

            if (!SHCreateMenuBar(&mbi)) 
            {
                g_hWndMenuBar = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                g_hWndMenuBar = mbi.hwndMB;
            }

            // Informationsstruktur für die Aktivierung der Shell initialisieren
            memset(&s_sai, 0, sizeof (s_sai));
            s_sai.cbSize = sizeof (s_sai);
            break;
        case WM_PAINT:
            hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

            // TODO: Hier den Zeichnungscode hinzufügen.

            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            CommandBar_Destroy(g_hWndMenuBar);
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

        case WM_ACTIVATE:
            // Shell über die Aktivierungsmeldung benachrichtigen
            SHHandleWMActivate(hWnd, wParam, lParam, &s_sai, FALSE);
            break;
        case WM_SETTINGCHANGE:
            SHHandleWMSettingChange(hWnd, wParam, lParam, &s_sai);
            break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Meldungshandler für Infofeld.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
            {
                // Erstellen Sie eine Schaltfläche "Fertig", und passen Sie die Größe an.  
                SHINITDLGINFO shidi;
                shidi.dwMask = SHIDIM_FLAGS;
                shidi.dwFlags = SHIDIF_DONEBUTTON | SHIDIF_SIPDOWN | SHIDIF_SIZEDLGFULLSCREEN | SHIDIF_EMPTYMENU;
                shidi.hDlg = hDlg;
                SHInitDialog(&shidi);
            }
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

        case WM_COMMAND:
            if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK)
            {
                EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
                return TRUE;
            }
            break;

        case WM_CLOSE:
            EndDialog(hDlg, message);
            return TRUE;

    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

The relevant code is just copied from msdn. However, I get the following error message:

```
unresolved external symbol "recv" referenced in function WinMain
```

There ar more errors, but they are all the same. The differences are the names of the functions (e.g. shutdown, send, ...)

I tried the code in a Win32-Console-Application, and it worked well!

Does anybody know, why this application doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for any of the Windows CE socket function (for example [`recv`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee494737.aspx)) you'll see that it specifically states that the LIB file you need is `ws2.lib`.

That means that you need to replace this section of your code:

```
// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib, Mswsock.lib, and Advapi32.lib 
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib") 
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib") 
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")
```

With this

```
#pragma comment (lib, "ws2.lib")
```

Comment: thanks!!! it works! I forgot to add windows ce as keyword while searching for the library ^^

Answer (score 0):

You need to link correct winsock library.

Make sure you have correct library paths.

Follow this article: [Creating a Basic Winsock Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[recv function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks, I have already followed the article. And I already have linked the library. It still doesn't work. Even if I set the whole path, it doesn't recognize the functions